# How can I restart the browser after driver.quit()?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

When I write a code like this:

```py
with webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service) as driver:
    driver.get("http://google.com")
    time.sleep(10)

with webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service) as driver:
    driver.get("http://google.com")
    time.sleep(10)
```

I encounter an error saying "ValueError: I/O Operation on closed file"
Is there anything that I could do to prevent this error?